# WooCommerce Image Upload Failed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello I'm facing some difficulties with uploading images.

upload image 4f4ac7816... fails orginal size 2.5MB.

upload image 6e507671e... succeeds orginal size 345KB.

I have looked into the upload limit and it's limited to 200MB so that's not the problem here.

As you can see the image starting with 4f4ac7816... only creates 3 size versions. There is something wrong here because I expected the same set of pictures like the others.
https://gyazo.com/7191407f7f748b9aa53a4caa29ded6fc

I'm using the update call from Product
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-a-product

Error received:

```
System.Net.WebException: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<title> 503 Service Unavailable
</title></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">503</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Service Unavailable
</h2>
<p>The server is temporarily busy, try again later!</p>
</div></div></body></html>
```

Expected : a updated product with new attached image ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. My image dimension is bigger then allowed. It should not be bigger then 2500px